# iOS 7.1 Simulator SKProductRequest request:didFailWithError: Cannot connect to iTunes

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, ios-simulator, app-store-connect

To validate the In-App Purchase products the following is executed:

```
- (void) validateProductIdentifiers:(NSArray *)productIdentifiers
{

    if (! self.productsRequest) {
        self.productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc]
                                      initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithArray:productIdentifiers]];
    }

    else {
        [self.productsRequest cancel];
        self.productsRequest = nil;
        self.productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc]
                            initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithArray:productIdentifiers]];
    }

    self.productsRequest.delegate = self;
   [self.productsRequest start];
}
```

In iOS 8.2 and 8.4 in the simulator, the start method call triggers with no issues.

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request
 didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{

    self.products = response.products;

    // Remove invalid identifiers
    for (NSString *invalidIdentifier in response.invalidProductIdentifiers) {
        [self removeInvalidBookWithId:invalidIdentifier];
    }

    [self.delegate listProducts];
}
```

Running on iOS 7.1 in the simulator the call-back encounters an iTunes connection error. The error: "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"

```
- (void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {}
```

I know that I can't make purchases from the simulator but it seems that if I can at least see the products in iOS 8.2 and 8.4 that I should be able to do so on iOS 7.1
Do I actually need a 7.1 device to test this?